# Is there a way to put a list of custom objects inside a custom object in cloud-firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, nested, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an android app for a university project using cloud firestore, and i wonder if it is possible to have inside a document a field being an array of custom object (The document is also itself a custom object)
I think it is some kind of nesting.

I am already able to use custom objects (Receipt). I have an arraylist of string representing Artciles. Curently those Strings that formatted so that I can parse it an read the price, the amount and the name of an article, but in the future i might need to add more data.
I thought about using a sub-collection, but I need to be able to download the entire document directly.

```java
public class Ticket{

    // TICKET DATA
    private Date date;
    private double cashIn;
    ...


    // ARTICLES LIST DATA
    private ArrayList<String> basket;//What I want to change

    public Ticket(){
        // EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR NEEDED
    }
//With other constructors, setters and getters and parsing code
```

If I replace the type inside my ArrayList to the custom object Type i get this error:

```
Could not deserialize object. Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.ereceipt.e_receipt.Objects.Article (found in field 'basket.[0]')
```

I make the 'conversion' from firebase to java object inside a on click callbackusing this:

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = // Some query (kind of big, you might not need it)
Ticket ticket = documentSnapshot.toObject(Ticket.class);
```

And here is the current Article class that will be upgraded later for future features:

```
public class Article{
    private String name;
    private int amount;
    private double unitprice;

    public Article(){

    }
    ...
}
```

My data base is composed only of one collection called receipt and a document is like this:

```
receipt/basket (an array)
receipt/basket[0]/name (String)
receipt/basket[0]/amount (number)
receipt/basket[0]/unitprice (number)
receipt/cashIn (number)
receipt/store/name (String)
receipt/store/address (String)
receipt/store/message (String)
receipt/timestamp
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.